# Difference between female and male usage

Tags: grammatical-gender, figures-of-speech, sounds

What explains the difference of a de facto larger frequency of vowels of one writer compared to another? In the statistics data I examined, a vowel had higher probability in the text from the female Swedish authoer compared to a Russian male author. The statistics I cite compared the male and female use of consonants and vowels indicated that the probability of next sound being a vowel was much higher for the Swedish female author compared to a Russian male author. The probability of next sound being a vowel and the probability of next sound being a consonant could be explained to vary by style, by book, by author, by language and/or by gender (male/female)

Making statistics on material either women or men wrote, I hypothesize that there are more vowels when the writer is a female and more consonants when the writer is male. Are there any evidence for or against my notion? Did anybody make a study like that? Does it have any purpose besides being a "fact"? A purpose I can think is revealing forgery when a man for instance in a text pretends to be a woman or vice versa, a woman writing to you pretending to be a man then according to patterns you could get an indication.

Edit: I changed it to a real hypothesis about how sounds change since we may wish to compare phoneticallly if doing a real study that could indicate for instance whether the next message is from a man or a woman.

Edit: The statistics say there is a statistical difference between 2 books specified as the markov matrix for if the next sound is a vowel or a consonant given that the current value is a vowel or a consonant.

Comment: Don't know about gender differences, but you should investigate [Stylometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry) .

Comment: *Making statistics* and *it seems to me* do not go very well together... Did you do a correct statistical analysis or not?

Comment: Maybe you can cite these statistics? Voting to close until you do.

Comment: Is this just your experience, or do you have a source that makes this claim?

Comment: I *guess* the same study with specific words would give much more interesting results.

Comment: It was the only statistical difference I had used and it was only between 2 authors, one male and 1 female. So it could be used to test which one of them, but then again it could have been style instead of gender. Model I used was probability of vowel following a consonant in a text I compared markov chains for just 2 authors. Making markov models for many authors I don't know would change the result.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with more about the background how to exaplain an actual difference since the study we're receiving here rejects the gender difference so style or mother tongue might explain an actual statistical difference.

Comment: @Niklas: So you're saying that a larger sample of authors might not change the result? I beg to differ. A sample size of 1 per group is what's called "anecdotal" evidence.

Comment: @Robusto Especially considering that there could be huge differences in vowel content between Russian and Swedish.

Comment: Exactly. What explains the difference between the female (Selma Lagelöf) and the male (Pushjkin) author? How do we understand the difference besides just establishing it in fact (or explain that there was no difference when I might expect a difference in female and male use if any.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just out of curiosity I have done some quick statistics.

I downloaded the following books from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/)

**Men writers**

- Alice's Adventures in Wonderland by Lewis Carroll
- Adventures of Huckleberry Finn by Mark Twain
- Moby Dick, or, the whale by Herman Melville
- The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle
- The Picture of Dorian Gray by Oscar Wilde
- Paradise Lost by John Milton
- The Works of Edgar Allan Poe — Volume 1 by Edgar Allan Poe
- War and Peace by graf Leo Tolstoy
- Dracula by Bram Stoker
- Treasure Island by Robert Louis Stevenson

**Women writers**

- Secret Adversary by Agatha Christie
- Jane Eyre by Charlotte Brontë
- Frankenstein by Mary Wollstonecraft Shelley
- Pride and Prejudice by Jane Austen
- Sarah Orne Jewett
- Ramona by Helen Hunt Jackson
- Home Influence by Grace Aguilar
- Middlemarch by George Eliot
- A Season at Harrogate by Mrs. Hofland
- Wuthering Heights by Emily Brontë

After removing the common *Project Gutenberg header*, I've read the files in R, split them into characters and let it count vowels and consonants.

I had a total of 8725700 characters for men and 11468186 for women

Here's a graph with the ratios consonants/vowels<sup>1</sup> calcolated *per book* (showing mean +/- standard deviation)

[image: Consonants/vowels ratio]

There is no statistical significance in the two groups (p=0.89, t-test)

**EDIT**

I played some more with the data and I got this bargraph of usage of the single letters.

[image: usage per letter]

Again, you can see no major differences between men and women writers

**EDIT2**: I repeated the analysis with 10 books per group. I would say that there is definitely no difference

---

<sup>1</sup> I considered *a, e, i, o and u* as vowels, the result does not grossly change including *y*.

Comment: The difference in use of _q_ is interesting, but running the same test on 26 samples and finding one of them to have statistical significance (even if _q_ does, which I didn't check) is not unusual, and likely not statistically significant. But IMO it's worth looking into with a larger sample: try a whole bunch of books and look for differences in _q_ use. (Of course, if one of the characters in any of those four novels by women has a _q_ in his name, then that explains everything.)

Comment: I haven't done the stats for the single letters. Anyway running 26 t-test would be wrong. I am not sure which is the best test to run here, as the variables are dependent on each other, probably some sort of linear model would do. I'll try and add some more books later ;)

Comment: Well, running tests is probably unnecessary, as you can see the proportions are about equal — except for _q_. So maybe add more books and just test _q_. 

_Do_ any of those four books have a character with a _q_ in his name? Wikipedia doesn't list any in the articles on the novels.

Comment: @msh210: that would be a biased way to test the differences, as you're deciding *post-hoc* what to test. Anyway, the culprit seems to be in Agatha Christie's book (pun intended) with the major contributors to the *Qs* being *quitely*, *question[s]*, *inquired*, and *quite*.

Comment: Nah. You've noticed a plethora of _q_s in four women's books as compared to four men's books, so you test fifty books from each sex to see whether there's a statistically significant plethora of _q_s in women's. Where's the bias in that?

Comment: @msh: I am not a statistician, but I believe doing only q is exactly like doing 26 t-tests: you cannot just ignore all of the other variables, especially because the frequency of q is dependent on the frequency of the other letters (as the sum of all frequencies equals 1). Plus, look at the error bar on the women's q...

Comment: Very interesting. I only had compared 2 authors using markovian model where probability of next sound being a vowel or a consonant is calculated. So if it's Russian it might have more consonants compared to French if comparing over language borders.

Comment: @msh: I repeated the analysis with 10 books per group and now you can see no difference at all.

Comment: On some level then we can reject a statistical difference. I'm just thinking what could explain an actual difference where there is one between 2 texts. You can find 2 books where one has a larger probability of a vowel following a consonant. The study I referred to compared books and found that one book/author/style had a larger probability using a markov chains the represent the probability of next being a vowel given a consonant and similar markov models for consonants and vowels. It can be a style or mother tongue difference when there is one instead of a gender difference.

Comment: @Niklas: well, sure, pick any couple of the books I've chosen and you're likely to see some difference. But if you only take 2 books there are too many disturbing factors, such as the nationality, gender and age of the writer, the use of slang, the type of writing (journal article, scientific writing, kid's novel etc) that you would not take into account. A proper analysis has to be done on a larger corpus I would say. But I am not an expert in text analysis...

Comment: @nico Thank you for developing the question in a constructive way. Questions I can think of are 1) How can an email program programmatically know whether a male or female authored the message? and 2) What explains the difference when different texts have different probabilities for changes between vowels and consonants?

Comment: @Niklas: as I was saying, I am not an expert in text analysis. Maybe looking at usage of specific words would be a better option?

Comment: @nico Yes. Either some difference of words or any pattern that could better than guess a writer's gender.